# How to convert dictionaries into an an array to populate table view

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to convert dictionaries returned from this  into an array from the Message struct to populate a table view. In the process of doing that I came across an error that reads

> "keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "messages", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with"

How do I resolve this? Please have a look at the code below:

```
  struct MessageResponse: Codable {
        let messages: [Message]
    }
    
    struct Message:Codable {
        
        var userID: String
        var username: String
        var avatarURL: String
        var text: String
        var messages:[String] = []
       
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case userID = "user_id"
            case username = "name"
            case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
            case messages = "message"
        }
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            userID = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .userID) ?? ""
            username = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .username) ?? ""
            avatarURL = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .avatarURL) ?? ""
            text = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .messages) ?? ""
           
            for message in messages{
                let chatInfo =  try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: Message.CodingKeys(rawValue:message)!)
                messages.append(chatInfo ?? "")
            }
   

func getChat(){
        ChatClient.shared.getMessages {  messageResponse in
            print(self.messages = messageResponse.messages)
        }
        
    }        }
```

---

This is the JSON that I am trying to decode

```
{ "data" : [ { "user_id" : "1", "name" : "Drew", "avatar_url" : "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/drew_avatar.png", "message" : "Team, can we give job applicants taking this test some examples of the types of apps they’d be working on if they joined our team?" }, { "user_id" : "2", "name" : "Abby", "avatar_url" : "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/abby_avatar.png", "message" : "We work on ecommerce apps for brands like PromGirl & Simply Dresses." }, { "user_id" : "3", "name" : "Taylor", "avatar_url" : "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/taylor_avatar.png", "message" : "You know those scooter sharing services that have been popping up? We developed and support one of those: Movo." }, { "user_id" : "2", "name" : "Abby", "avatar_url" : "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/abby_avatar.png", "message" : "We do a lot of hardware-pairing apps as well like Conair’s Smart WeightWatchers Scale and Phlex’s new smart goggles." } ] }
```

Comment: What does converting dictionaries into an an array mean? (not my grammatical mistake)

Comment: If somebody says "I came across an error," you say what?  Where!?  At which line?

Comment: For your information, your 'data' guy is an array of a dictionary.

Comment: Hi it's not an array. Initially when I tried to parse it, the error shown was "expected to parse array but instead found dictionary instead"

Comment: Why do you need  a custom decoder? Try without it.

Comment: Your dataset contains four keys.  Where do 'text' and 'messages' come from?  What are `CodingKeys` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a custom decoder. Besides that your main issue is your `MessageResponse` messages property key should be "data"

---

```
// MARK: - MessageResponse
struct MessageResponse: Codable {
    let messages: [Message]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case messages = "data"
    }
}
```

---

```
// MARK: - Message
struct Message: Codable {
    let userID, name: String
    let avatarURL: String
    let message: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id", name, avatarURL = "avatar_url", message
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let json = """
{ "data" : [ { "user_id" : "1", "name" : "Drew", "avatar_url" : "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/drew_avatar.png", "message" : "Team, can we give job applicants taking this test some examples of the types of apps they’d be working on if they joined our team?" }, { "user_id" : "2", "name" : "Abby", "avatar_url" : "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/abby_avatar.png", "message" : "We work on ecommerce apps for brands like PromGirl & Simply Dresses." }, { "user_id" : "3", "name" : "Taylor", "avatar_url" : "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/taylor_avatar.png", "message" : "You know those scooter sharing services that have been popping up? We developed and support one of those: Movo." }, { "user_id" : "2", "name" : "Abby", "avatar_url" : "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/abby_avatar.png", "message" : "We do a lot of hardware-pairing apps as well like Conair’s Smart WeightWatchers Scale and Phlex’s new smart goggles." } ] }
"""
```

---

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(MessageResponse.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print:

> MessageResponse(messages: [__lldb_expr_9.Message(userID: "1", name: "Drew", avatarURL: "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/drew_avatar.png", message: "Team, can we give job applicants taking this test some examples of the types of apps they’d be working on if they joined our team?"), __lldb_expr_9.Message(userID: "2", name: "Abby", avatarURL: "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/abby_avatar.png", message: "We work on ecommerce apps for brands like PromGirl & Simply Dresses."), __lldb_expr_9.Message(userID: "3", name: "Taylor", avatarURL: "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/taylor_avatar.png", message: "You know those scooter sharing services that have been popping up? We developed and support one of those: Movo."), __lldb_expr_9.Message(userID: "2", name: "Abby", avatarURL: "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/abby_avatar.png", message: "We do a lot of hardware-pairing apps as well like Conair’s Smart WeightWatchers Scale and Phlex’s new smart goggles.")])